# Passing ArrayList of custom object to kSOAP function

Tags: android, ksoap

This is the function which is to call the function in the server to perform some task. But i have to pass in a ArrayList and a String value. I have trouble passing the ArrayList to the server. Can anyone tell me what i should do?

```
public void findLocation(ArrayList<APData> apdatalist, String profilename){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "FindLocation");

    PropertyInfo quotesProperty = new PropertyInfo();
    quotesProperty.setName("profileName");
    quotesProperty.setValue(profilename);
    quotesProperty.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(quotesProperty);

    request.addProperty("AP_List", APData.class);

    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpRequest = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpRequest.debug = true;
    String result = "";

    try
    {
        httpRequest.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.e("Request",httpRequest.requestDump.toString());

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.e("Response",httpRequest.responseDump.toString());

        result =  response.toString();
        if(result == null){
            Log.e("AndroidRuntime", "No location result is return!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return temp;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Sorry... still yet to found a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a possible solution. I've modified the SoapSerializationEnvelope class to deal with ArrayList. 
I modified the method 
`public void writeObjectBody(XmlSerializer writer, KvmSerializable obj)`

```
public void writeObjectBody(XmlSerializer writer, KvmSerializable obj) throws IOException
{
    // Added this code for parsing attributes of KvmSerializable objects

    int cnt = obj.getPropertyCount();
    PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        Object prop = obj.getProperty(i);
        if(!(prop instanceof SoapObject)) {
            // prop is a PropertyInfo
            obj.getPropertyInfo(i, properties, info);

            // Added this code to parse ArrayList objects in requests
            if(prop instanceof ArrayList<?>){
                ArrayList<?> values = (ArrayList<?>)prop;
                for(Object o : values){
                    writer.startTag(info.namespace, info.name);
                    writeProperty(writer, o, info);
                    writer.endTag(info.namespace, info.name);
                }
            }else if ((info.flags & PropertyInfo.TRANSIENT) == 0)
            {
                writer.startTag(info.namespace, info.name);
                writeProperty(writer, obj.getProperty(i), info);
                writer.endTag(info.namespace, info.name);
            }
        } else {
            // prop is a SoapObject
            SoapObject nestedSoap = (SoapObject)prop;
            writer.startTag(nestedSoap.getNamespace(), nestedSoap.getName());
            writeObjectBody(writer, nestedSoap);
            writer.endTag(nestedSoap.getNamespace(), nestedSoap.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me

Comment: how and where to call this method